# Antlr production producing a bunch of single element arrays

Tags: antlr, antlr4

My grammar is working, but I have a bunch of elements in the tree that are single element arrays, and I don't really understand why. I tried reading the information about visitors, but I'm pretty sure the "problem" is with the grammar and perhaps its verbosity. Does anything jump out here? Or perhaps I'm just visiting things incorrectly. In the example below I do not react to visitFnArgs or visitArgs, but just visitFunctionCall. Things like function arguments and statements seem to sometimes be wrapped in single element arrays.

```
grammar Txl;

root: program;

// High level language
program: stmt (NEWLINE stmt)* NEWLINE? EOF # Statement
    ;

stmt: require    # Condition
    | entry      # CreateEntry
    | assignment # Assign
    ;

require: REQUIRE valueExpression;
entry: (CREDIT | DEBIT) journal valueExpression (IF valueExpression)? (LPAREN 'id:' valueExpression RPAREN)?;
assignment: IDENT ASSIGN valueExpression;

journal: IDENT COLON IDENT;

valueExpression: expr # Expression;

expr: expr (MULT | DIV) expr         # MulDiv
    | expr (PLUS | MINUS) expr       # AddSub
    | expr MOD expr                  # Mod
    | expr POW expr                  # Pow
    | MINUS expr                     # Negative
    | expr AND expr                  # And
    | expr OR expr                   # Or
    | NOT expr                       # Not
    | expr EQ expr                   # Equality
    | expr NEQ expr                  # Inequality
    | expr (LTE | GTE) expr          # CmpEqual
    | expr (LT | GT) expr            # Cmp
    | expr QUESTION expr COLON expr  # Ternary
    | LPAREN expr RPAREN             # Parens
    | NUMBER                         # NumberLiteral
    | IDENT LPAREN args RPAREN       # FunctionCall
    | IDENT                          # Identifier
    | STRING_LITERAL                 # StringLiteral
    ;

fnArg: expr | journal;
args: (fnArg (',' fnArg)*)?;

// Reserved words
CREDIT: 'credit';
DEBIT: 'debit';
IF: 'if';
REQUIRE: 'require';

// Operators
MULT: '*';
DIV: '/';
MINUS: '-';
PLUS: '+';
POW: '^';
MOD: '%';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
LBRACE: '[';
RBRACE: ']';
COMMA: ',';
EQ: '==';
NEQ: '!=';
GTE: '>=';
LTE: '<=';
GT: '>';
LT: '<';
ASSIGN: '=';
QUESTION: '?';
COLON: ':';
AND: 'and';
OR: 'or';
NOT: 'not';
HASH: '#';
NEWLINE : [\r\n];
WS: [ \t] + -> skip;

// Entities
NUMBER: ('0' .. '9') + ('.' ('0' .. '9') +)?;
IDENT: [a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*;
EXTID: [a-zA-Z0-9-]+;
STRING_LITERAL : '"' (~('"' | '\\' | '\r' | '\n') | '\\' ('"' | '\\'))* '"';
```

This input:

```
require balance(assets:cash) + balance(assets:earnings) > AMT
```

Produces the following single element arrays:

```
SINGLE ELEMENT INSTRUCTION MathOperation (>)
SINGLE ELEMENT INSTRUCTION JournalReference { identifier: 'assets:cash' }
SINGLE ELEMENT INSTRUCTION JournalReference { identifier: 'assets:earnings' }
```

I wonder if partly my problem is I'm not visiting things properly. Here's my Math visitor:

```
  visitMath(ctx) {
    const visited = this.visitChildren(ctx);
    return new MathOperation(
      visited[0],
      ctx.getChild(1).getText(),
      visited[2],
    );
  }
```

But I assume the problem is in the thing that contains the math operation, which I think is visitRequire:

```
  visitRequire(ctx) {
    return new Condition(this.visitExpression(ctx.getChild(1)));
  }
```

Or perhaps in visitValueExpression or visitCondition, which are not overridden in my visitor.

Comment: "Things like function arguments and statements seem to sometimes be wrapped in single element arrays." Can you clarify that? `FunctionCallContext.args()` should return an object of type `ArgsContext`, not an array. Same for `ConditionContext.require()` (returning a `RequireContext`) etc. Lists should only be involved if a non-terminal appears multiple times in the same production or if it's quantified by a `*` etc. So I don't see why you'd encounter lists (or arrays) in the places you mentioned. `ArgsContext.fnArg()` would give you a list (of arguments), but that's what you'd want, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really short answer:  There's nothing wrong with single element arrays.  If there was only one instance of a thing that *could* exist multiple times, then it has to be an array (or List), and that list will have only the one item, if that's how many there are.

Antlr won't "unwrap" a single item to not be in an array.  (That would only be valid in untyped languages or languages that allow Union types, and would be a pain to use as you'd always have to check whether you had a "thing" or a list of "thing"s)

Any time the "same type of thing" *can* exist more than once when matching a rule, ANTLR will make that available as an Array/List of that type.

Eample:

```
journal: IDENT COLON IDENT;
```

has 2 `IDENT` tokens, so it'll be made accessible via the context as a List of those types

(in Java, I'm not positive which language you're using).

```java
public List<TerminalNode> IDENT() { return getTokens(TxlParser.IDENT); }
```

Two of your examples are of "JournalReference" so this would explain getting a list (if you use the `ctx.IDENT()` or the `ctx.getChild(n)` methods).

If I change the Journal rule to be:

```
journal: j1=IDENT COLON j2=IDENT;
```

I've given names to each `IDENT` so I get individual accessors for them (in addition to the IDENT() accessor that returns a list:

```java
    public static class JournalContext extends ParserRuleContext {
        public Token j1;
        public Token j2;
        public TerminalNode COLON() { return getToken(TxlParser.COLON, 0); }
        public List<TerminalNode> IDENT() { return getTokens(TxlParser.IDENT); }
```

With the labels you can use `cox.j1` or `cox.j2` to get individual tokens.  (of course you'd name them as appropriate to your use case).

since the `FunctionCall` alternative of the `expr` rule uses the `args` rule

```
args: (fnArg (',' fnArg)*)?;
```

and that rule can have more than one fnArg, the it will necessarily be a list of `fnArg`s in the context:

```java
    public static class ArgsContext extends ParserRuleContext {
        public List<FnArgContext> fnArg() {
            return getRuleContexts(FnArgContext.class);
        }
```

There's really not much you can do (or should want to do to not have that in a List, there can be one or more of them.

Since non of the code you present shows where you're writing your output, its a bit difficult to be more specific than that.

Your `visitMath(cox)` example is also a bit perplexing as `math` is not a rule in your grammar, so it would not exist in the Visitor interface.

I would suggest taking a closer look at the `*Context` classes that are generated for you.  They'll provide utility methods that will be much easy to use and read in the future than `getChild(n)`.  `getChild(n)` is obscure, in that you'll have to refer back to the rule and diligently count rule members to determine which child to get, and it is also VERY brittle, in that `n` will change with any modification to your grammar.  (Maintainers, or future you, will appreciate using the utility methods instead.)

Comment: Updated post with sample input and more detail about where the single element arrays are.

Comment: The lhs/rhs thing didn't seem to change anything, though it does seem useful.

Comment: I've revised the answer to be more specific given revised question.

Comment: The visitMath thing is just a "generic" called from each of the math related visitors. I should've been more specific about that. Most of the arrays you describe seem "right". But I don't get why the FUNCTION rule itself ends up in an array, or the math ones. It's like there's some other rule above it that I am NOT overriding the visit method for, and then the default "visitChildren" returns an array. If this is true, then I guess the question is should I fix it or is it fine to just deal with it in visitor methods.

Comment: What language are you using?  In Java, the Visitor is defined as a generic class (public class TxlBaseVisitor<T> extends AbstractParseTreeVisitor<T> implements TxlVisitor<T> ) where T is the return type of all visitor methods. So, yeah, all visit*() methods return the same type, but you determine that when you implement your visitor (a derived class).  All return values need to be of class <T>, but you can define a base class and return sub-classes of that class if you want slightly different results depending upon the node you're visiting.

Comment: Any visit*() method you don't override returns null unless you override "defaultResult()", then it's up to you what to return, as long as it conforms to the <T> type.  Take a look at AbstractParseTreeVisitor (https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java) to see the default implementation of visitChildren(), it's the method called by all of the visit*() methods in the base class unless you override them.

Comment: I was using Javascript, but now using Java and muddling through understanding the diff. Problem right now is it's not generating "visitExpr" and I don't see why...

Comment: It’s generating specific enter*|exit* methods for each alternative in your expression rule.  (visitMulDiv, visitAddSub, etc). And each will have a context “custom designed“ just for that alternative. It’s much easier than one visitExpr that has to sort out which alternative it’s looking at.